# Solve differential equation: $x \frac {dy}{dx} = 1 − y^ 2$ to find $y$ in terms of $x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve differential equation :

$$x \frac {dy}{dx} = 1- y^2$$
Find $y$ in terms of $x$.

I've got upto here :  $3y-y^3 = \ln|\frac x2|$, if it's correct.

How do I get $y$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: That result doesn't look right. You can write this as $$\frac{1}{1-y^2}\,dy = \frac{1}{x}\,dx$$

Comment: If your result were right, Rct, you'd have a hard time solving for $y$. Fortunately, @Thomas has shown you the right way to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have following @Thomas Andrews suggestion

$${1\over 2}\log{|{1+y\over 1-y}|}=\log{|x|}+C$$

Which leads to

$$y(x)={k\cdot x^2-1\over k\cdot x^2+1}$$